# When I have to use dereference in git and why?

Tags: git, dereference

We use tags for deployment of versions, when I execute command:

```
git ls-remote -t origin
```

I can see such picture

```
d5a0a2513d71dd94522039d9844daf8b8eed531f    refs/tags/live-0.0.1
43a6228d4bf5839aa934b541c35d19b897b35056    refs/tags/live-0.0.1^{}
a8662ef8bf021ea349dbf56970fd9f62f97093fb    refs/tags/live-0.0.2
b48d63ff5af0c9f488f99c2066824c8891ae394e    refs/tags/live-0.0.3
```

I can't find on my local rep this revision **d5a0a2513d71dd94522039d9844daf8b8eed531f**.
Please, explain, when we have to use dereference? Maybe someone has an idea why it was done at my situation?(Maybe it was done by me, but I don't remember, maybe was testing something) And why I can't see this commit **d5a0a2513d71dd94522039d9844daf8b8eed531f** at local rep?

Comment: do you have the same tags on your local repo?

Comment: git tag -l
live-0.0.1
live-0.0.2
live-0.0.3

Comment: and what is its commit? `git show-ref live-0.0.1`

Comment: @charlesB, It's strange. For me also it shows the first tag twice, second one with `^{}`. `git log` doesn't show the commit from the first tag, but only the second. `git show-ref` on the other hand, correctly shows the commit of first tag but doesn't show anything for the second

Comment: `git show-ref live-0.0.1
d5a0a2513d71dd94522039d9844daf8b8eed531f refs/tags/live-0.0.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In git, SHA-1 hashes are used to identify all objects, not only commits. Object types include:

- Trees
- Blobs
- Commits (revisions)
- Tags

Not all tags have their own SHA-ID. There are two types of tags:

- Lightweight (without message, they are more like a branch that cannot be moved)
- Annotated (created as a separate object, because tag message must be saved somewhere)

Annotated tag contains message and commit SHA-ID, which is presented as a result of dereference (`43a6228` in your case) and is identified itself as an object with ID (`d5a0a25`), which is required to retrieve tag message.

So, you always need to dereference tags if you are looking for commit identifiers. Anyway, any tag name is always a valid commit identifier itself.

Comment: Thank you, and to show annotation we can use command `git tag -l -n1`